# Unable to remove join from two feature layers

Tags: arcpy, error-000800

Trying to remove the joins between two feature layers gets me this result after running each line individually through the interpreter:

```
MakeFeatureLayer("Y:/Desktop/Data/Levels_copy.shp","tempLevels")
<Result 'tempLevels'>
MakeFeatureLayer("Y:/Desktop/Data/Points_copy.shp","tempPoints" )
<Result 'tempPoints'>
AddJoin("tempPoints", "LEVEL_ID", "tempLevels", "LEVEL_ID")
<Result 'tempPoints'>
RemoveJoin("tempPoints", "tempLevels")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6161, in RemoveJoin
        raise e
    ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of  | Levels_copy.
    Failed to execute (RemoveJoin).
```

Am I missing something? Do the feature layers not exist in memory by the time I try to remove the joins?

#### Update

The joins still seem to exist as this codeblock still gives me fields from both shapefiles:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("tempPoints").fields
for f in desc:
    print f.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating it more thoroughly, the proper remove join would have been:`RemoveJoin("tempPoints", "Levels_copy")`

From [esri's own documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/remove-join.htm):

> If the join table was a dBASE file named MyTable.dbf, the join name
>   would be "MyTable"; so to remove it, specify "MyTable".

A small detail, but one that can easily be overlooked since the feature layers are not technically independent objects.